# Problema con Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema con este método, necesito pasarle una archivo .jpg pero al parecer no está reconociendo la carpeta o la imágen y me aparece lo siguiente:

```
[![Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at Login.LoginUI.addLogo(LoginUI.java:101)][1]][1]





 private void addLogo(JPanel panel1) {
                JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
                label1.setFocusable(false);
                label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource
("images/ruipi4.png")).getFile()));
                panel1.add(label1);
                label1.setBounds(55, 146, 200, 110);
            }
```

La imágen se encuentra en la carpeta resources tal como se muestra en la imagen. Gracias

Aquí se aprecia el programa cuando comento el método addLogo y su declaración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Hola Daniel cuando creas un nuevo objeto de la clase ImageIcon solo debes pasar la ruta de tu imagen asi:

```
public class Ventana {

public void init(){
    //objeto de la clase JPanel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //utilizo el metodo addLogo pasando el panel
    addLogo(panel);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


private void addLogo(JPanel panel1) {
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setFocusable(false);
    label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/nombreDeTuImagen.png"));
    panel1.add(label1);
    label1.setBounds(55, 146, 200, 110);
}
```

}

lo probé en mi computador y funciono espero te resuelva el problema saludos

Comment: Hola @Tomás Salgado intenté lo que me sugeriste sin embargo no consigo que el método addLogo reconozca la imagen y me salta la excepción por ser null, es solo esa parte porque cuando retiro el método y el llamado al método el programa ejecuta normalmente de la siguiente manera: dejo el link para que veas la imágen me sugerirías algo?:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWo6zcf71PsKi1E8kWyw9fMEZ1Fn5KZB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola Daniel, podrias escribir el codigo de tu clase con problemas tal cual lo tienes ahora, para verlo completo y asi poder ayudarte de mejor manera. Te deje mi codigo igual para que lo veas

Comment: Buenas tardes Muchachos cabo de encontrar la solución y resulta que no era nada relacionado con el código sino simplemente dar click derecho sobre la carpeta y elegir la opción Build Path, luego en Use as Source Folder e inmediatamente el IDE me la reconoció como mi carpeta predeterminada de recursos y me permitió ejecutar el rpograma correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que se presenta aquí es porque no estás mandando la ruta (tanto absoluta como relativa) para que este acceda a la imagen correspondiente. Te recomendaría utilizar algo así en tu código:

```
label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("\\images\\image.jpg")));
```

Recuerda utilizar `\\` ya que a la hora de realizar tu ruta tendrás problemas con la utilización de `\` , ya que este lo confundirá como un escape (como `\n`).

Comment: Hola @Tristán intenté lo que me sugeriste sin embargo no consigo que el método addLogo reconozca la imagen y me salta la excepción por ser null, es solo esa parte porque cuando retiro el método y el llamado al método el programa ejecuta normalmente de la siguiente manera: dejo el link para que veas la imágen https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWo6zcf71PsKi1E8kWyw9fMEZ1Fn5KZB/view?usp=sharing 

me sugerirías algo?